# retrofit header not change immediately

Tags: java, android

In my app I have a `spinner` that includes some language abbreviation example (en, az, and others), I want to set selected language abbreviation as the request header and I need this in every request so I am saving abbreviation in shared preferences and get abbreviation in my `ApiClient` class,
every time that spinner selection has changed I change shared preferences abbreviation value but header only set the first time I select a language and when I change spinner selection header not change

**This is my ApiClient class**

```
private static final String BASE_URL = ApiUrls.server_url;

public static Retrofit getClient(Context context)
{

    SharedPrefUtil sharedPrefUtil = new SharedPrefUtil(context);
    String locale = sharedPrefUtil.getSelectedLanguage();

    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    httpClient = httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException
        {
            Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().header("Accept-Language",
                    locale).build();

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).client(httpClient.build())
            .build();

    return retrofit;
}
```

**This is my ApiRequester class method for sending a request to server**

```
public static void sendLogin(final Context context, Map<String, String> params,
                             final HttpResponses.onLoginSuccess onLoginSuccess) {

    DialogHelper.ProgressDialog progressDialog = showWaitDialog(context);

    if (hasInternetConnection(context)) {
        params.put("grant_type", "password");
        params.put("client_id", "raymon-client");
        params.put("client_secret", "raymon-secret");

        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient(context).create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<ResponseBody> call = apiService.loginRequest(params);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                //result ok
                if (response.code() == 200)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        onLoginSuccess.loginResponse(JsonSuccessParser.parseLoginResponse
                                (context, response.body().string()));

                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else if (response.code() == 403)
                {
                    onLoginSuccess.loginError(response.code());
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        JsonErrorParser.parseServerError(context,response.errorBody().string());

                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                showNoConnectionDialog(context);
            }
        });
    } else {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        showNoConnectionDialog(context);

    }


}
```

**This is my code for setting language abbreviation in shared preferences**

```
private void setUserLocale()
{
    String selected_country = countryCodeAdapter.getItem(country_code_spinner.
            getSelectedItemPosition()).language.abbreviation.toLowerCase();

    LocaleHelper.setLocale(this,selected_country);
}
```

How can I change header immediately when user change spinner position?

Answer (score 1):

In `ApiClient` class, you should initialize `locale` variable inside of `interceptor` methods to reflect your changes.

Example)

```
private static final String BASE_URL = ApiUrls.server_url;

public static Retrofit getClient(Context context)
{
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    httpClient = httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException
        {
            SharedPrefUtil sharedPrefUtil = new SharedPrefUtil(context);
            String locale = sharedPrefUtil.getSelectedLanguage();
            Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().header("Accept-Language",
                    locale).build();

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).client(httpClient.build())
            .build();

    return retrofit;
}
```

However, if the value changes constantly, it may be possible to explicitly **pass the value of the Header as an argument to the Service** instead of the Interceptor.

Example)

```
public interface ApiService {
    Call<...> loginRequest(@Header("Accept-Language") String language, @QueryMap Map<String, String> params);
}

public static void sendLogin(final Context context, Map<String, String> params,
                             final HttpResponses.onLoginSuccess onLoginSuccess) {

    DialogHelper.ProgressDialog progressDialog = showWaitDialog(context);

    if (hasInternetConnection(context)) {
        params.put("grant_type", "password");
        params.put("client_id", "raymon-client");
        params.put("client_secret", "raymon-secret");

        SharedPrefUtil sharedPrefUtil = new SharedPrefUtil(context);
        String locale = sharedPrefUtil.getSelectedLanguage();

        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient(context).create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<ResponseBody> call = apiService.loginRequest(locale, params);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                //result ok
                if (response.code() == 200)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        onLoginSuccess.loginResponse(JsonSuccessParser.parseLoginResponse
                                (context, response.body().string()));

                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else if (response.code() == 403)
                {
                    onLoginSuccess.loginError(response.code());
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        JsonErrorParser.parseServerError(context,response.errorBody().string());

                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                showNoConnectionDialog(context);
            }
        });
    } else {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        showNoConnectionDialog(context);

    }
}
```